# Building a kernel module from several source files which one of them has the same name as the module

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

Is it possible to build a kernel module from several source files which one of them has the same name as the module?

For example:
I want to build "mymodule.ko" with the following source files:
mymodule.c
mymodule_func.c

This makefile doesn't work:

```
#Makefile
obj-m += mymodule.o
mymodule-objs := mymodule.o mymodule_func.o
```

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a solution, I placed my source file in a sub folder:

Makefile
src/mymodule.c
src/mymodule_func.c

```
#Makefile
obj-m += mymodule.o
mymodule-objs := ./src/mymodule.o ./src/mymodule_func.o

all:
    make -C $(KERNEL_PATH) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KERNEL_PATH) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Make sure your cross-file functions aren't marked static.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to rename mymodule.{c,o} to mymodule_main.{c,o} and not bother with the extra subdirectory?

Answer (score 25):

Proper way to fix in kernel make file would be as:

```
# 
obj-m+= my_module.o

#append other source files except my_module.c which would be include by default
my_module-objs+= src1.o src2.o
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I found it to be the most helpful one here.

Comment: This approach didn't work for me, maybe it depends on the kernel/kbuild version. I did not investigate it further...

Comment: @MarcusS module name shouldn't same as source file name. I changed file name different with module, It works!

Answer (score 9):

As per my understanding it is not possible to have the module name and the source name to be the same. It would be better to provide module name as `module.o` and use the Makefile for compiling loadable kernel module as shown below,

**Makefile**

```
# If KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    **obj-m := module.o
        module-objs := mymodule.o mymodule_func.o**
    # Otherwise we were called directly from the command
    # line; invoke the kernel build system.
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DDEBUG
else
    KERNELDIR   := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD         := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif
clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: A useful way to define `KERNELDIR` is using `?=` instead of `:=` so that it defaults to building for the currently running kernel, but can be overridden on the make command line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TARGET` to name your .ko file as I did in this example:

```
TARGET = can

KDIR = /lib/modules/3.1.10-1.16-desktop/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m += $(TARGET).o

can-objs := can_core.o can_open.o can_select.o can_sysctl.o can_write.o \
       can_close.o can_ioctl.o can_read.o can_util.o \
       can_debug.o can_error.o \
       can_async.o can_sim.o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

So after the build I ended with a bunch of object files and `can.ko`

Comment: If I add a can.o object in can-objs, i get make[2]: Circular can.o <- can.o dependency dropped. The can.o file won't be link

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create symlink to the file, say:

```
mymodule.c: ln -sf mymodule.c _mymodule.c
```

Now, use `_mymodule.o` as the object name:

```
mymodule-objs := _mymodule.o
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has stumbled upon this issue while working with **Xilinx SoCs** and **petalinux**, note the generated .bb (bitbake) file. Apart from specifying object files in the Makefile:

`modulename-objs+= src1.o src2.o`

all files (including headers) must be listed in the modulename.bb file's `SRC_URI` variable.