# < insmod: ERROR: could not insert module GSM.ko: Unknown symbol in module. > How to fix it?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I have written a simple loadable kernel module. To create a character device file in /dev/ and a related class directory. The following lines I have added in the project.

```
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("GSM driver");
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Guruprasad");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple driver");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");
```

While building I got the following warning

```
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /home/.../char_dev_gsm/GSM.o
```

While inserting I got the following error :

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module GSM.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Please help me with this.

The project has one main file (GSM.c) and an include file (device.c and device.h)

Please get the files from the following link.
https://github.com/guruprasad-92/Device-Driver

I've tried with adding the line `MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");` in file device.c which results no warning messages and no error messages as well, but while inserting the module it neither creates the device file `/dev/gsm0` nor updating the `$dmesg` with `printk()` related messages.

I have also tried with writing the functions `register_dev()` and `unregister_dev()` in the file GSM.c which did not results any warning, and created the the device `/dev/gsm0` and class directory in /sys/class/

But I want to know why the file inclusion is giving warning while building.

Comment: Running `dmesg` after attempting to load the module should show which symbol was unknown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a kernel module from several source files which one of them has the same name as the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the module is GSM.ko is built from multiple .c files (GSM.c and device.c), and the basename of the module is the same as the basename of one of the .c files (which is only allowed when the module is built from a single .c file).

To fix it, you can rename GSM.c to (for example) gsm.c and change the `GSM-objs` line in the Makefile:

```
obj-m := GSM.o
GSM-objs = gsm.o device.o
```