# GET WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() when LKM is Compiled with Multiple Src files

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a LKM named `RtmNetlinkLKM.c` and compiles and run fine. The moment I update its Makefile to compile with other src files, it starts giving warning:

```
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE()
```

The following  `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` is already present in kernel module file.

**Previous Makefile, module compiles fine**

```
obj-m += RtmNetlinkLKM.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

**updated Makefile, module now compiles with a warning**

```
obj-m += RtmNetlinkLKM.o
RtmNetlinkLKM-objs += rt_kern.o gluethread/glthread.o << Added two more sources
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) clean
    rm -f rt_kern.o
    rm -f gluethread/glthread.o
```

When compiled using second Makefile, it gives stated warning. When I add `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")` in `gluethread/glthread.c` , warning goes away. I don't understand, why do I need to add "GPL" license in `glthread.c` when it is not a module but contain functions to be used by module (It is a linked list mini-library). Why doesn't it complain with other src file `rt_kern.c` in a similar way. I had never made any changes in original module file `RtmNetlink.c` throughout this process.

Comment: List `RtmNetlinkLKM-objs` specifies object files to be created (from corresponded sources). This list contains `rt_kern.o` and `gluethread/glthread.o`, but doesn't contain `RtmNetlinkLKM.o`. (Well, the list simply couldn't contain `RtmNetlinkLKM.o` as Linux kernel build system doesn't support listing of an object file with the same name as the target module.)

Comment: So, r u suggesting to include RtmNetlinkLKM.o to the list or not sir ? Even if i add, same warning still coming up.

Comment: See that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gautham Kantharaju in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam) provided by @Tsyvarev for solving my problem. While compiling multiple source files into a single module, the main reason for the warning seems to be, ".. it is not possible to have the module name and the source name to be the same."

If anyone else has the same question, I think following `Makefile` should solve the issue.

```
# give your module a different Name

obj-m += newModuleName.o
newModuleName-objs += RtmNetlinkLKM.o rt_kern.o gluethread/glthread.o 

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) clean
```