# Can't correctly build Linux kernel module with object file

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I have several files: so called library and kernel module, which uses functions from this library. All files are in the same directory.

*lib.c*:

```
#include <linux/module.h>    
#include "lib.h"   

volatile int check = 0;

int lib_in(void)
{
     check = 5;
     printk(KERN_ERR "In -> check:%d\n", check);
     return 0;
}
void lib_out(void) { printk(KERN_ERR "Out\n"); }
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

*lib.h*:

```
int lib_in(void);
void lib_out(void);
```

*some_mod.c*:

```
#include <linux/init.h>    
#include <linux/module.h>    
#include <asm/string.h>    
#include "lib.h"   

static int __init mod_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "Loaded\n");
    return lib_in();
}

static void ______wtf; mod_exit(void) // syntax error
{
    printk(KERN_ERR "Unloaded\n");
    lib_out();
}

Plain text - here also should be syntax error

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

While build it somehow doesn't compile some_mod object file (and even check its code), but it emits `some_mod.ko`. By the way it compiles `lib.c`. So the module could be correctly inserted but there is no output from `printk`.
P.S. the errors in *some_mod.c* were added to underline that this code is not even compiled. That is the problem.

*Makefile*:

```
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)

TARGET = some_mod
LIB = lib 

obj-m := $(TARGET).o
#$(TARGET)-y := $(LIB).o
$(TARGET)-objs := $(LIB).o

all: default
default:
     make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
     make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you want to build a module from several files one of which has the same name as the module itself. See there how to handle that: [Building a kernel module from several source files which one of them has the same name as the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam)

Answer (score 0):

The `wtf` line reads like a mix of a symbol definition error `static void ______wtf;` and `mod_exit()` missing a type.  Try replacing the line with:

```
static void __exit mod_exit(void)
```

Delete the line with `Plain` and rebuild.

After no errors, a successful compile and link, and successful `insmod`, output from printk() should be visible on console, the system `messages` file, or both.

BTW, if you see any build errors about unresolved symbols, review your Makefile for `.o` files.

Comment: I have no errors. That's the problem. I mentioned that it successfully builds and inserts. Without compiling the code in *some_mod.c*.

Comment: *"should be visible"* - you can try it to make sure. If code does not compile - errors in it have no matter.

Comment: There's something strange here. Try renaming, eg `mv some_mod.c sm.c`; add `sm.o` to the line `$(TARGET)-objs` .  What are your results?

Comment: Answers in question mentioned by Tsyvarev helped. The name of target must be different from the source file names.