# Kernel module makefile compiles but gives undefined errors on execution

Tags: linux, makefile, module, kernel

I´m trying to compile a kernel module which has a included .h file in it.
At the moment the follow files are used;

```
main.c
gpiodriver.c
gpiodriver.h
```

The makefile:

```
 #CC=/usr/local/xtools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-cc

 PROG = main

 $(PROG)-objs := gpiodriver.o
 obj-m += $(PROG).o

 all: $(PROG)

 $(PROG): $(OBJ)
     make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/local/xtools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin/arm-linux- -C 
 ~/felabs/sysdev/tinysystem/linux-2.6.34 M=$(PWD) -o $(PROG) modules

 clean:
     make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

Honestly I'm not that good with the makefile, so my guess is that I'm doing it completly wrong..

Comment: I can only suppose that you came up with that makefile by attempting to use another module's makefile as a model.  There's nothing inherently wrong with referring to examples, but you really ought to use them as a *supplement* to the documentation for [the kernel build system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/index.html).  In this case, it sounds like the section on [building external modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html) would be particularly relevant.  Relying on the docs is even more important if your makefile-fu is weak.

Comment: The problem is that you build a kernel module from several files, one of which has the **same name** as the module itself. See that question for possible solutions: [Building a kernel module from several source files which one of them has the same name as the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam)