# Makefile to linux kernel module with multiple source files

Tags: c, linux, makefile, module, kernel

I'm learning Linux Kernel programming. I'm trying to build my module from multiple files. It builds and loads, but there is no messages in dmesg. What is going wrong?

***solution.c:***

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include "checker.h"

static const char* msg = "Hello from my module!";
extern void call_me(const char*);

static int __init init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "322\n");
    call_me(msg);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "After the function\n");
    return 0;
}

 static void __exit exitFromModule(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "BYE\n");
    return;
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(exitFromModule);
```

***checker.h:***

```
#include <linux/module.h>
 void call_me(const char* str);
```

***checker.c:***

#include "checker.h"
#include <linux/kernel.h>

```
void call_me(const char* str)
{
    printk("<1>FROM CALL_ME!\n");
    return;
}
```

***Makefile:***

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/misc
TARGET = solution

obj-m := $(TARGET).o
solution-objs  :=  checker.o

all:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD)  modules

clean:
        make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
        @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order;
        @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
        @rm -fR .tmp*
        @rm -rf .tmp_versions
```

After that i start make and it compiles. But after insmod there is messages in dmesg.

Comment: Are you getting anything in dmesg? The prints from the `init` functions? Can you attach the dmesg from before and after loading the module?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, no, there is nothing.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya. sorry, i'm newbie and i'm unable to post images. There is my output. I've cleaned dmesg and it is empty after module inserting.

alex@alex-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD:~/l2$ sudo dmesg -c
alex@alex-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD:~/l2$ sudo insmod solution.ko
alex@alex-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD:~/l2$ sudo dmesg
alex@alex-Lenovo-ideapad-100-15IBD:~/l2$

Comment: The line `solution-objs  :=  checker.o` means that your module is compiled only from the ``checker.c`` file. You need to add **all** source (objects) files into `xxx-objs` list. But you cannot add object with the same name as the module itself, for that you need either to rename a module or a source file. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam) for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a kernel module from several source files which one of them has the same name as the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam)

Comment: @Tsyvarev, well, it builds but i have an error: insmod: ERROR: could not insert module module.ko: Invalid parameters. What can be wrong?

Comment: Probably, `dmesg` contains additional information about this error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yes. you're right. Thank you.