# Linux Kernel Module ignores main module file when an additional source file is added

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kbuild

I'm trying to build a loadable kernel module that includes another source file. I have the following in a Makefile or Kbuild file:

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
mymodule-y += other_src_file.o
```

In this scenario, `other_src_file.c` will be compiled. Strangely, the main source file `mymodule.c` will not be compiled. Intentional syntax errors are not caught. An object file `mymodule.o` is still produced, as is the `.KO` file. Loading this module on the target platform has no effect.

If I instead remove the second line in the Makefile/Kbuild that includes the other source file, my intentional syntax errors are caught. In a minimal example, `init_module()` will run and dmesg shows what I put into printk. It would not print anything prior to removing the line with `other_src_file.o`, despite being unchanged.

So what I find is that by including an additional source file (whether it is being used or not), the main module/C file is effectively ignored. An LKM is produced, but it has no effect from what I can see. Using --debug confirms in the latter case that `mymodule.c` is used (pipe into grep returns literally anything) whereas the former shows that there is not a single reference to `mymodule.c` (but many to `other_src_file.c`)

I've also tried setting up the makefile as the following, but there's no behavioral difference.

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
mymodule-y += other_src_file.o

all:
    make -C ../../../ M=($PWD) modules # -C points to the root of my kernel
clean: 
    clean -c ../../../ M=$(PWD) clean
```

The output of `make` looks like the following:

```
LD some/path/mymodule/built-in.o
CC[M] /some/path/mymodule/other_src_file.o <-- notice it's the only CC; nothing for mymodule.o
LD[M] /some/path/mymodule/mymodule.o
Building modules, stage 2
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /some/path/mymodule/mymodule.mod.o
LD[M] /some/path/mymodule/mymodule.ko
```

When that other src file is left out, there is a line that shows `mymodule.o` being compiled.

I'm running in an Ubuntu 20.04 (VM) on x86_64. The kernel is 3.1.10, make is 4.2.1.

I feel like I'm missing something simple (unfamiliar with linux building, fairly familiar with C and compiling otherwise). Would greatly appreciate a pointer here.

Comment: My favored solution is to name all the source files so that none of their base names is the same as the module's name, e.g. use `obj-m += mymodule.o`⏎ `mymodule-objs := mymodule_main.o other_src_file.o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
obj-m += mymodule.o
```

tells KBuild system just to build a **module** named `mymodule`.

The sources compiled into that module depend from variable `mymodule-y`:

- If the variable is set (like in your code), then source list it taken **only** from this variable. There is no "automatic" addition of `mymodule.c` source.
- If the variable is not set, then, **by default**, the module is compiled from the source which has the same name.

Note, that one cannot build a module `mymodule` from **several sources**, one of which is `mymodule.c`, that is has the **same name** as the module itself.
Either module or the source file should be renamed. That situation is described in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606075/building-a-kernel-module-from-several-source-files-which-one-of-them-has-the-sam).

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. That fixed my issue. I found the question you linked a couple hours after posting this. I'm sure this is in the documentation somewhere for module building, but it wasn't particularly obvious from an initial parsing.